# Enable "double-click to zoom" when using `titlebarAppearsTransparent=true`

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

When building an app for macOS, and setting `titlebarAppearsTransparent = true`, or settings "Transparent Title Bar" the .XIB file in Xcode, you lose the default behavior of double-click to trigger Window>Zoom command.

Does anyone know how can I get that functionality back? Do I have to manually make the call to `NSWindow.zoom()`?

We're actually making a Flutter app, and it would be nice if we didn't have to write a native extension to make this one call. Hoping there's a setting or something that can re-enable it.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: We ended up writing some native code for this, you can find the usage here: 
https://github.com/gskinnerTeam/flutter-folio/blob/master/lib/_utils/native_window_utils/macos_window_utils.dart and the native methods we added to the macOs runner here: https://github.com/gskinnerTeam/flutter-folio/blob/master/macos/Runner/MainFlutterWindow.swift